# Is it possible to build FreeGLUT on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, opengl, makefile, freeglut

I'm doing [some tutorials on OpenGL](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tutorial%2001.html) that use [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/).

[Apparently](http://lookass.ch/?id=4area=artart=216&area=art&art=221) this is how you build and install it on the mac:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/X11R6/include" ./configure --prefix="${PWD}/../"
make
make install
```

Unfortunately this on its own gives me an error when I do the `make` command: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`

After doing abit of work I've found that an improvement on the first line is:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/X11R6/lib" ./configure --prefix="${PWD}/../"
```

Unfortunately when I do the `make` command I'm still getting an error:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../..   -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -I../../../include  -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -MT smooth_opengl3-smooth_opengl3.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/smooth_opengl3-smooth_opengl3.Tpo -c -o smooth_opengl3-smooth_opengl3.o `test -f 'smooth_opengl3.c' || echo './'`smooth_opengl3.c
smooth_opengl3.c:101: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5080: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:102: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5078: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:103: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5082: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:104: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5197: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:105: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5222: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:106: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5195: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:107: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5196: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:108: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5193: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:109: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5221: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:110: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5223: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:111: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLGETSHADERIVPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5209: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGETSHADERIVPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:112: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5210: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:113: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLGETPROGRAMIVPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5207: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGETPROGRAMIVPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:114: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5208: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:115: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLGETATTRIBLOCATIONPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5206: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGETATTRIBLOCATIONPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:116: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5280: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:117: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLENABLEVERTEXATTRIBARRAYPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5202: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLENABLEVERTEXATTRIBARRAYPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:118: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLGETUNIFORMLOCATIONPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5212: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGETUNIFORMLOCATIONPROC’ was here
smooth_opengl3.c:119: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLUNIFORMMATRIX4FVPROC’
/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5242: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLUNIFORMMATRIX4FVPROC’ was here
make[4]: *** [smooth_opengl3-smooth_opengl3.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This has been [documented on the net before](http://www.bytecompile.org/wiki/doku.php/installing-freeglut), but the solution isn't really all that helpful in this instance. I've also tried swapping it for the GLUT.framwork that comes with OS X, but the examples are using FreeGLUT-specific functions.

Comment: Ok, I've got a little further in this. Using `CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib" ./configure --prefix="${PWD}/../"` gets rid of the 'Undefined symbols' error. But now I get `ld: library not found for -lGL` \ `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` \ `make[2]: *** [libglut.la] Error 1` \ `make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1` / `make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: Maybe you should also check with LDFLAGS, `-L/usr/X11R6/lib` is needed.

Comment: Ooh thanks. Ok so I used `CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/X11R6/lib" ./configure --prefix="${PWD}/../"` and I got rid of the previous error. Now I get a whole load of errors along the lines of `smooth_opengl3.c:101: error: redefinition of typedef ‘PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC’` \ `/usr/X11R6/include/GL/glext.h:5080: error: previous declaration of ‘PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC’ was here`

Comment: Would you update your question accordingly, so that I can start an answer? Excessive comments of conversations are not recommended in this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XQuartz 2.7.2 swapped to FreeGLUT (2.8.0) instead of the old MesaGLUT.  So provided you have OS X version 10.6.3 or later, you can just install XQuartz 2.7.2 or later.  See:

- http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.2
- http://lists.apple.com/archives/x11-users/2012/Apr/msg00020.html

Comment: For those who're wondering how to set up freeglut in XCode, see http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/01_hello_opengl/mac/xcode/index.php

Answer (score 4):

[It was suggested](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/xquartz-dev/2009-April/002304.html) on Xquartz's mail list, that the freeglut demo is wrong to declare those PFN*PROC twice.

So, by simply commenting out those double-definition from smooth_opengl3.c, the free glut would pass the compilation phase. However, from my experience, it would not run and give some error about the GLSL.

It was also suggested that [GLUT framework should be used](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3a-FreeGlut-and-Mac-OSX-p15355299.html) on Mac OS X.

Comment: Unfortunately, OSX's GLUT framework doesn't support OpenGL 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

It´s working for me with the following parameters to configure:

```
./configure  CFLAGS="-I/usr/X11/include/X11/extensions -L/usr/X11/lib" LIBS="-lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi" --with-x --x-includes=/usr/X11/include
```